# How to preserve the field case sensitivity in ksql while creating the stream form schema registry by specifying the topic name

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

created the stream using schema-registry without specifying the filed name refer below

```
  CREATE STREAM sample_avro WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='test',VALUE_FORMAT='AVRO');
```

Topic name `test` contains a few fields and values when described the topic all the fields in topic are shown in the uppercase example given below

```
 ksql> describe sample_avro;

    Name : SAMPLE_AVRO
    Field | Type
    ---------------------------------------
    ROWTIME | BIGINT (system)
    ROWKEY | VARCHAR(STRING) (system)
    ID | INTEGER
    FIRSTNAME | VARCHAR(STRING)
    LASTNAME | VARCHAR(STRING)
    EMAIL | VARCHAR(STRING)
    REG_DATE | BIGINT
```

from this link [ksql-cases](https://rmoff.net/post/how-ksql-handles-case/) filed case sensitivity is maintained only by specifying a filed name while creating the stream.

suppose topic contains 1000 record user cannot create the stream by specifying all the field name.

so kindly help me to slove this issue

Answer (score 4):

This is just how KSQL currently works. You can comment on this issue if it would be useful to you to retain the case of the soure Avro schema: https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/2415.